# android get full path to my application via share option

Tags: android, file, android-intent, types, mime

I am writing an application where my application should show as option when user shares a file ( any type image or normal text file or pdf or with with no extension)

I know it for file like image by adding image/* as data in manifest file and i can able to handle image as URI.

But I needed it for any file type.

Another example is, I open file browser and select a file (can be any type) then in share option my application should appear to handle.

How can I modify my application for this case

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mimeTypes for all file types you wish to handle.

More information at:
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: how can I do that in my manifest file?. My application not going to open or do anything except taking the full path and use the path as string.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to update your manifest according to the mimeTypes of files you wish to handle.
After that, You will need to handle the incoming data in your code.
You have all of the information on the link I have attached to my answer.
Again, You will need to add mimeType for each file type you wish to handle.